# Cannot find keyframe css rule on ipad webview

Tags: javascript, css, ipad

I try to rewrite the below css keyframe rule using javascript. It works on  normal desktop safari and ipad safari browser but not in ipad webview.

css

```
@-webkit-keyframes "scroll" {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    55% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }




function findKeyframesRule(rule)
{
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < ss[i].cssRules.length; ++j) {
            if (ss[i].cssRules[j].type == window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE && ss[i].cssRules[j].name == rule)
                return ss[i].cssRules[j];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

findKeyframesRule("scroll");  // it returns null ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ipad webview has a old safari engine and so It not supports new standard syntax and would not takes in the css rules list.

```
@-webkit-keyframes "scroll" {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    55% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }


function findKeyframesRule(rule)
{
    var ssheets = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = ssheets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var cssRules = ssheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var j = ssheets[i].cssRules.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (cssRules[j].type == window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE && cssRules[j].name == rule){
                        return cssRules[j];
                }
        };
    };
    return null;
}
```